# Getting Dailies out of the Middle East

Tags: video

Asking for a friend.

We're presently scouting locations in Jordan for a feature shoot, it'll go about five weeks. We're shooting with an ARRI Alexa and generating ArriRaw dailies. We're working with the idea that we'll be generating about half a terabyte of dailies a day on the high side, including multichannel sound. We're cutting and doing post in Los Angeles.

What is the most reliable way of getting the dailies out of country? The last time my friend shot in the area he shipped his dailies out and they were impounded for months by customs, and under the current regime we have no idea what would happen and we want other alternatives (it also doesn't help that Jordan now borders a hot war zone). We're toying with shipping to Europe and from there ingesting into AWS, anyone have any experience with that?

Comment: I was going to suggest AWS. Not sure about crazy customs stuff. Try https://travel.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There must be a special media visa you can apply for. Then bring all the dailies with you when you leave, instead of shipping them. The big media companies must have some sort of fast track.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered any file transfer accelerators like [Aspera](http://asperasoft.com/) or [File Catalyst](http://filecatalyst.com/)?

They use a different network protocol to send your files over and give you significant transfer speed gains.